# The sum of m-th consecutive integers for primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

I’m looking at the sum of m-th powers of consecutive integers

i.e. $Sm(p) = 1^m + 2^m +…+(p-1)^m$

I need to prove:
Let $p$ be an odd prime. Prove the following congruences:

$$\begin{align}
Sm(p^2) &\equiv 0\pmod{p^2}\text{ if $(p − 1)$ does not divide m}\\
Sm(p^2) &\equiv -p\pmod{p^2}\text{ if $(p − 1)$ divides m}
\end{align}$$

For all $m > 1$

I recognize that in order to solve using primitive roots I will need to eliminate the multiples of p in the expansion.

Could someone please show me how to prove it?

Comment: I think it's modulo $p^2$

Comment: Use http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226023/congruence-modulo-p OR   http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1049420/for-any-positive-number-k-find-the-value-of-1k-2k-3k-p-1kmod

Comment: There are also completely elementary solutions (i.e., not using primitive roots), if you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

Partial Solution.

If we assume that $m$ is odd, then we know that $(p-1)$ does not divide $m$ (as $p-1$ is even). We are then in the first case. In this situation, the claim follows from the fact that $$m\;odd\implies\frac {(n-1)n}2\;|\;S_m(n)$$

(see, eg, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/427744/showing-that-1k2k-dots-nk-is-divisible-by-nn1-over-2/427751#427751) )